# Удаление "подсписка" из списка

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Нужно удалить из списка в вхождения, да не просто по элементам, а прям множество. Т.е. если есть список: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 3, 7]`, и например, кортеж, который удаляемых элементов `(1, 5, 3)`, нужно, чтобы в итоге получился список `[0, 1, 2, 3, 7]`.

Как можно легче всего такое реализовать?

Comment: Сразу вопрос, что делать в ситуации `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4]` и `(1, 2, 1)`?

Comment: удаляется первое вхождение

Comment: Это разовое действие или оно должно часто выполняться?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Отвечу так: из первого комментария должно получиться `[2, 1, 3, 4]`, но если будет повтор `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]` - в итоге должно получиться `[2]`. Это действие в коде выполняется в цикле, сначала подается один кортеж, потом другой и так далее, пока список не закончится.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы попробовал что-то вроде такого:
1) изменение списка на месте (чуть сложнее)

```
def is_equal(lst, pattern):
    if len(lst) != len(pattern):
        return False
    for a, b in zip(lst, pattern):
        if a != b:
            return False
    return True

def clear_list(lst, pattern):
    index = []
    l = len(pattern)
    rng = iter(xrange(len(lst)))
    while True:
        try:
            i = next(rng)
            if is_equal(lst[i:i+l], pattern):
                for j in range(i, i + l):
                    index.append(j)
                    if j != i + l - 1:
                        next(rng)

        except StopIteration:
            break
    index.reverse()
    for i in index:
        del lst[i]

l = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1]
p = (1, 2, 1)
clear_list(l, p)
print l # --> [2, 1, 3, 4, 1]
```

Оно даже работает.

---

2) для генерации нового списка (все проще):

```
def clear2(lst, pattern):
    res = []
    l = len(pattern)
    r = iter(xrange(len(lst)))
    while True:
        try:
            i = next(r)
            if is_equal(lst[i:i+l], pattern):
                for j in range(i, i + l - 1):
                    next(r)
            else:
                res.append(lst[i])
        except StopIteration:
            break
    return res

l = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2]
p = (1, 2, 1)
print l
print clear2(l, p) # -> [2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

---

Потестил на 5 примерах, оба варианта рабочии.

Comment: 1- Используйте Питон 3 код, если вопрос явно просит Питон 3 код. 2- можно упростить примеры (*"Как можно легче всего такое реализовать?"*), например, см. [`delete_sublist()` (аналог `clear_list()`)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/495262/23044) и [`removed()` (аналог `clear2()`)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/495480/23044)

Answer (score 5):

Фактически условие эквивалентно удалению подстроки из строки:

```
>>> list(bytes([0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 3, 7]).replace(bytes((1, 5, 3)), b''))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 7]
```

Вот простой «в лоб» `O(n*m)` алгоритм по удалению `subseq` подпоследовательности из `lst` списка:

```
def removed(lst, subseq):
    subseq = type(lst)(subseq) # копируем, чтобы тот же тип был (для == ниже)
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        if lst[i:i+len(subseq)] == subseq: # нашли подпоследовательность
            i += len(subseq) # пропускаем
        else:
            yield lst[i] # передаём как есть
            i += 1
```

Пример:

```
>>> list(removed([0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 3, 7], (1, 5, 3)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 7]
```

Можно заметно улучшить производительность (до `O(n)` вместо `O(n*m)`) в некоторых случаях, с помощью [алгоритмов, используемых для нахождения позиции подстроки в строке в Питоне (Boyer-Moore + Horspool и Sunday)](http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm).

Можно модифицировать алгоритм, чтобы принимать на вход произвольные итерируемые объекты, а не только последовательности. Или чтобы изменять входной список по месту без создания копии.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю и свой пример :)

```py
def find_sublist(l, m):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        try:
            if tuple(l[i: i + len(m)]) == tuple(m):
                yield i, i + len(m)
        except IndexError:
            pass

def delete_sublist(l, m):
    for i, j in find_sublist(l, m):
        del l[i: j]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_equal(lst, pattern):
    for a, b in zip(lst, pattern):
        if a != b:
            return False
    return True

def get_idx(lst, pattern):   
    n = len(lst)
    m = len(pattern)
    rng = xrange(n - m)
    idx = -1
    for i in rng:
        if is_equal(lst[i:i+m], pattern):
            idx = i
            break;     
    return idx

def del_pat(lst, pattern):
    idx = get_idx(lst, pattern)
    ans = lst
    if idx > -1:
        a =  lst[:idx]
        a.extend(lst[idx + len(pattern):])
        ans = a
    return ans
```

Comment: я там поправил чуть `is_equal` в таком виде она для конца списка работает неверно.

Comment: @andy.37 Я отступил от конца списка, поэтому такая проблема не должна возникнуть. `rng = xrange(m - n)`

Comment: Что-то у меня Ваш код ничего не меняет... Да и rng у Вас нигде не используется.

Comment: @andy.37 по ошибке не то скинул, сейчас исправлю.

Comment: ага, я так и думал, у Вас только первое вхождение паттерна убирает.

Comment: @andy.37 если не ошибаюсь, именно это и требовалось.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35970/discussion-between-andy-37-and-).

Comment: да, нужно убирать было оба вхождения, просто если кортеж `(1, 2, 1)`, а список `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]` - то должно выйти `[2]`

Comment: 1- можно использовать `find` имя вместо `get_idx` для читаемости. 2- `del_pat` удаляет только первое вхождение, а нужно удалять все вхождения (цикл нужен).

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [0,1,2,3,1,5,3,7]
tpl = (1,5,3)

# создаем строки из lst и tpl

s_lst = ""
for l in lst:
    s_lst += str(l)

s_tpl = ""
for t in tpl:
    s_tpl += str(t) 

# методом replace() производим замену всех вхождений s_tpl на "" в s_lst
# и делаем из обработанной строки список

new_lst = []
for i in s_lst.replace(s_tpl,""):
    new_lst.append(int(i))

print(new_lst)
```

Comment: 1. Просто подумайте, что у Вас получится, если `lst = [1,11,111,1111]` 2. Работает только для списка из целых (1 пункт поправить не хитро)