# Как работает оператор in в вызове print(1,2,3 in b)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как работает оператор in для одного элемента понятно, но я нигде не нашел инфы как он работает для последовательности.

```
b = [1,2,3,1,3]
print(1,2,3 in b)

#1 2 True
```

Не понимаю почему он не проверяет число 3.

```
print(1,2 in b)
#1 True
```

Тут проверяется только первый элемент. Оператор in работает только с один элементом?

Используется Python 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда вы делаете `print(1,2,3 in b)`, то вы передаете в функцию `print` три параметра: `1`, `2` и `3 in b`. Получается, что просто 1 и 2 как есть выводятся на экран, а для третьего параметра происходит проверка попадания в список.

Даже если добавить скобки `[1,2,3] in b`, то будет проверяться вхождение списка `[1,2,3]` как элемента списка `b` (т.е. если бы было `b = [1,2,3,[1,2,3],1,3]`, то получили бы `True`). Подобная проверка вида `'abc' in 'abcdef'` работает для строк, но не работает для списков.

Как сделать нужную вам проверку без циклов, я пока вам навскидку не скажу.
Просто рабочий пример, дающий нужный результат, может быть таким:

```
b = [1,2,3,1,3]
a = [1,2,3]
print(any(a == b[i:i+len(a)] for i in range(len(b)-len(a))))
```

Comment: Добавлю. Для строк такая проверка работает потому что в питоне нет концепции символа, даже индексатор у строки возвращает другие строки.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, даже если бы был символьный тип, ничего не мешало бы реализовать и `'a' in "abcde"`, и `"abc" in "abcde"` (одиночные кавычки - "гипотетический" символьный тип). Просто для списка возможна глубокая вложенность, а у строк вложенности нет.

Answer (score 5):

Для того чтобы проверить содержатся ли все элементы (без учета повторяющихся) одного списка в другом  - можно воспользоваться `set.issubset()`:

```
In [189]: b = [1,2,3,1,3]

In [190]: a = [2,1]

In [191]: set(a).issubset(b)
Out[191]: True

In [192]: set([4,1]).issubset(b)
Out[192]: False
```

Comment: учитывая, что не ясно, какую именно операцию автор подразумевал, используя синтакс `1,2,3 in b`, то лучше явно словами сказать какого результата ваш код хочет достичь (или вопрос поправить, чтобы яснее был). К примеру, ваш код не будет работать, если фактическое намерение `bytes([1,2,3]) in bytes(b)` (поиск подсписка в списке). Связанный вопрос: [python3, удаление “подсписка” из списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/495480/23044)

Comment: @jfs, согласен, теперь указал явно...

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как найти элементы во втором списке состоящие из элементов первого?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/592836/23044)

Answer (score 0):

если порядок при сравнении неважен(ответ MaxU)
то не следует сравнивать как `set`, те вместо

`set(a).issubset(b)`

следует сравнивать как

`all(e in b for e in a)` либо `all(map(b.__contains__, a))`