# Как определить является ли один список частью другого?

Tags: python, списки

Подскажите, как определить, является ли один список частью другого?
Есть списки:

```
ls1=[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 24, 32, 48, 96]
ls2=[1, 97]
ls3=[1, 2, 7, 14, 49, 98]
ls4=[1, 3, 9, 11, 33, 99]

g1=[1,2]
```

Как определить, что **весь список** `g1` является частью списков `ls1` и `ls3`?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [elegant-find-sub-list-in-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106901/elegant-find-sub-list-in-list)

Comment: Уточните, что в вашем понимании значит для списка быть частью другого списка. Нужно чтобы та же последовательность элементов была подряд в другом списке? Или достаточно чтобы просто те же элементы присутствовали без учёта их порядка? От этого существенно будет меняться решение.

Comment: связанный вопрос [python3, удаление "подсписка" из списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/495034/23044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set(list_1).issubset(list_2) # Входит ли list_1 в list_2 ?
set(g1).issubset(ls1)        # True
set(g1).issubset(ls2)        # False
set(g1).issubset(ls3)        # True
set(g1).issubset(ls4)        # False
```

Comment: Это не сохраняет порядок, смежность элементов. К примеру, [2,1] список не является частью [1, 3, 2] списка: все *элементы* списка присутствуют в другом, но сам список не является подсписком, также как `'ам'` не является подстрокой `'мама'`: `'ам'` not in `'мама'`.

Comment: @jfs 'ам' in 'мама' is True

Comment: @eri: верно. Можно `'мм' not in 'мама'` в качестве примера использовать (чтобы увидеть, что set  в ответе число элементов игнорирует) или `'cb' not in 'abcd'` (set не сохраняет порядок), `'ac' not in 'abcd'` (set не сохраняет смежность).

Comment: 'cb' not in 'abcd' - лучший пример)

Answer (score 6):

```
def sublist_in_list(sub, lis):
    return str(sub).strip('[]') in str(lis).strip('[]')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

```
def check(lst, sub):
   for i in range(0, len(lst)):
       if lst[i:i+len(sub)] == sub:
           return True
   return False

print(check([1,3,2,4,6], [1,2])) # False
print(check([4,5,6,1,2], [1,2])) # True
```

Answer (score 1):

похоже на @godva, но меньше операций

```
list1 = [1,2,3,1,3,2,1]
list2 = [3,2]

list2_in_list1 = False

i=0
while True:
    try:
        i = list1.index(list2[0],i)
    except:
        break
    if i >=0:
        list2_in_list1 = list1[i:i+len(list2)] == list2
        if list2_in_list1:
            break
    i+=1

list2_in_list1
```

Answer (score 1):

Изучаю языки второй день, но вот такое придумал. Чувствую, что как-то можно присвоить разные переменные по индексу к каждому значению в списке, но не знаю как, было бы круче.)))

```
for x in g1:
    if x in list(ls1): 
        print('ls1 = true')
        break

for x in g1:
    if x in list(ls3):
        print('ls3 = true')
        break
```

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, как ваше решение отвечает на вопрос в этом топике?

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее простой вариант - через множества, но он подходит только в том случае, если в списке нет повторяющихся значений или их повторяемость некритична:

```
def sublist(g1, list2test):
    return set(g1) <= set(list2test)
```

Можно еще так:

```
def func(g1, list2test):
    ls1 = [i for i in g1 if i in list2test]
    ls2 = [e for e in list2test if element in g1]
    if ls1 == ls2: return True
    else: return False
```

Answer (score 0):

А можно немного рекурсии:

```
def is_in_list(lst_one, lst_two):
    if lst_two != []:
        if lst_two.pop() in a:
            is_in_list(lst_one, lst_two)
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

1ое услове - это признак выхода из рекурсии

2ое услове проверяет элемента второго списка в первый (и сразу второй список обрезается на этот элемент и ф-я вызывается снова)

предполгается, что список, вхождение которого мы проверяем в основной - заведомо меньше, чем этот самый "основной"

и в принципе этому алгоритму всё равно, есть ли повторяющиеся элементы или нет

P.S Внимание. Для этого алгоритма мы считаем, что один список является вхождением в другой в случае, если все элементы первого списка являются также элементами второго списка. То есть мы не следим за строгим совпадением индексов этих элементов.

Answer (score 0):

**Пример задачи с решением.**
На вход программе подается натуральное число nn, затем nn строк, затем число kk — количество поисковых запросов, затем kk строк — поисковые запросы. Напишите программу, которая выводит все введенные строки, в которых встречаются все поисковые запросы.

Формат входных данных
На вход программе подаются натуральное число nn — количество строк, затем сами строки в указанном количестве, затем число kk, затем сами поисковые запросы.

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести все введенные строки, в которых встречаются все поисковые запросы.

Примечание. Поиск не должен быть чувствителен к регистру символов.

```
n = int(input())
m = 0
a = []
b = []
c = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append(input())
k = int(input())    
for i in range(k):
    b.append(input())    
for i in range(n):
    ii = a[i]
    m = 0
    for j in range(k):
        jj = b[j]
        if jj.lower() in ii.lower():
            m += 1
    if m == k:
        c.append(ii)
print(*c, sep='\n')
```